# How does Xaml-AttachedAttribute work for child nodes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind, attached-properties

I'm currently trying to understand how some piece of Xaml actually works. The Xaml looks as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedEvents}}"
          GridViewColumnHeader.Click="SortableListViewColumnHeaderClicked">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="A" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ...}"
                            Width="80"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

My question is about the [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) "GridViewColumnHeader.Click" (second row). Somehow it is applied to all the GridViewColumnHeaders that are implicitly defined by the columns. I tried to reimplement this functionality in the code behind, but I failed, because I don't have access to the GridViewColumnHeaders, even when traversing the VisualTree...

Can someone give me a pointer at how this is implemented?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Short answer: It's not [attached attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx), but [attached events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx). And suddenly I find the right tutorials to understand what's going on!

In the code behind I do the same with

```
listView.AddHandler(ButtonBase.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(SortableListViewColumnHeaderClicked));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not attached properties but [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx):

> Functional definition: A routed event is a type of event that can invoke handlers on multiple listeners in an element tree, rather than just on the object that raised the event.
>
> Implementation definition: A routed event is a CLR event that is backed by an instance of the RoutedEvent class and is processed by the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) event system.

Specifically [attached events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx).

> The XAML language also defines a special type of event called an attached event. An attached event enables you to add a handler for a particular event to an arbitrary element. The element handling the event need not define or inherit the attached event, and neither the object potentially raising the event nor the destination handling instance must define or otherwise "own" that event as a class member.
>
> The WPF input system uses attached events extensively. However, nearly all of these attached events are forwarded through base elements. The input events then appear as equivalent non-attached routed events that are members of the base element class. For instance, the underlying attached event Mouse.MouseDown can more easily be handled on any given UIElement by using MouseDown on that UIElement rather than dealing with attached event syntax either in XAML or code.

---

To execute the same logic in code you call [`AddHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.addhandler.aspx) on the `ListView` and pass the [`ClickEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.clickevent.aspx) field.

Comment: That was the right pointer. Thanks for saving me hours of running into the wrong direction!